# Python "string-or-string-list" type convention?

Tags: python, string, list

I am writing some library functions in which I find myself wanting the functions to accept as input either a string, or a list-of-strings, and return the same type.

I have thought of a couple of approaches to this, but both seem clumsy. For each conceptual function I could write:

- a separate function for string and for string list. But that requires the calling code to know the type of the variable, and select the appropriate function.
- just one function, which decides what to do based on detecting the type of input using 'isinstance(inputarg, str):'. That at least hides the multiple choices inside the library instead of in the caller.

But I'm wondering if there's some more elegant approach or idiom that I've overlooked?

Clarification: Of these two solutions I much prefer the second, making a single function which is polymorphic to the extent of accepting (and returning) string or list-of-string. However, even in that case, switching based on `isinstance()` seems like an inelegance that perhaps has a better alternative.

Comment: I rarely desire to treat a single value as a sequence of such values.. can you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: does the list of strings do something other than apply the logic used by for a single string to each element in the list, possibly returning a list of the resulting values?

Comment: Just to be completest, you could have a function that takes two args (one of each type) and uses whichever isn't None. But I think that fails the "elegant" test. :-) Depending on expected usage, a varargs might make sense. I like both of your approaches. Name the method and args nicely.

Comment: @lfLoop The functions I have in mind apply the same logic to each individual strings as to a single string.

Comment: @user2864740 Example functions: replace_illegal_characters(arg); replace_special_substrings(arg, dict-of-replacements) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isinstance is OK.

Better is to test for the presence of some method you require for strings (and not lists), and test again for some method you require for lists (and not strings), and raise an AssertionError if you get neither.

You can test for methods using hasattr().

Comment: Note that a string *is* a sequence of strings. So unless you're specific that it needs to be a `list`, and not any other kind of sequence like a `tuple`, you can't really test for some method you require for sequences and not strings. You can test the other way around, things on string that aren't on other sequences. Of course, ideally there's some function of string that you actually *use* when the input is a string, in which case you can just go ahead and use it, catch the exception when it's not a string, and do the thing you do for a sequence of strings.

Comment: Clarifications: string = sequence of characters (ie: not sequence of strings). Also, @dstromberg's idea to test for method of list is fine so long as done after check for string. But point taken, checking first for a sequence would unwantedly accept a string.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to have just a single function taking an iterable of strings. If you need to call it with a single string `s`, you could always call it as `f([s])` or as `f((s,))`.

Comment: That's an additional approach, but this still requires the caller to know the type of s, and call f() differently for string vs list-of-strings.

Comment: @gwideman: Push the problem up the call stack, i.e. to the caller's caller. :)

Comment: @gwideman Usually one does know the types (modulo sub- and duck typing) of all variables. You can't really write much useful code without that knowledge. Is there something special about your callers that means they'll likely not know the type?

Comment: @NPE I see the :) so I assume that proliferating the non-polymorphism is not a serious suggestion :).

Comment: Alternatively, make the functions take a single-string and let the caller `map` (or whatever) as appropriate.

Comment: @user2864740: That's a good point. If the sequence version of the function simply applies the scalar version to each element, then `map()` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Regarding map: Again that's making the caller do something different depending on whether the variable is a string or list-of-string.

Comment: @gwideman: My earlier suggestion still stands: push the problem up the call stack. Someone up the stack will probably know what it is that they are dealing with.

Comment: @NPE: The issue is not that the type is unknown to some higher level caller. The issue is to avoid having to write separate logic for each type except at the lowest level. A la generics. And at that lowest level, is switch-on-isinstance() the way to go, or is there some cleverer idiom given that the types are string and list-of-string.

Comment: @gwideman: I think the question would benefit from a clear, convincing example.